# Ubuntu 20.04 Booting Problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, 20.04

Due to some reasons, I've installed `Windows 10` on `hdd`, while `Ubuntu` was already installed on `ssd`. Most of the time, I use Ubuntu but when I start my system, Windows is booted every time unless I press `F9` and select Ubuntu from the boot menu. It's very annoying to open the `boot menu` every time I run my laptop. `How can I set Ubuntu as the default OS?`

**Note:** I've tried to set Ubuntu as the default OS in Startup and Recovery (Windows) and Grub Customizer (Ubuntu). These solutions didn't work for me.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to change the boot order in UEFI > Boot. What you tried so far couldn't possibly work.

Comment: Thank you :) @ChanganAuto